# HttpServletRequest Nested Headers

Tags: java, servlets, oauth

I am implementing an OAuth 1.0a (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) consumer and need to access the header name and values that are nested in the Authorization header in the request.

Currently ...

```
request.getHeader("oauth_version").equals("1.0");
```

returns false because "oauth_version" is nested under the Authorization header. Given an HttpServletRequest object, how can I access the nested headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official concept of nested http header. In this case the header is "Authorization" and it contains a string representing oauth parameters. You have to parse it yourself or using a third party library.

You can find some examples at [oauth.googlecode.com](http://oauth.googlecode.com). More specifically, look at the `decodeAuthorization()` method in [this class](https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/commons/src/main/java/net/oauth/OAuthMessage.java). It uses regular expressions to parse the oauth parameters.

Comment: Thanks David, that makes sense. I appreciate the links to examples.